# How to populate the list in an s:select tags using hashmap?

Tags: struts2

Can you help me with the jsp that I'm doing? What I need to come up is to have my dropdown list using s:select in struts2 to have list values that will be coming from a hashmap in an action.

I haven't read anybody to answer this question properly when I read some of the forums asking this same question.

in my Action class, I have this hashmap:

```
    private HashMap<String, String> nationalities ;

     public HashMap<String, String> getNationalities () {
    return nationalities ;
}

public void setNationalities(HashMap<String, String> nationalities) {
    this.nationalities = nationalities;
}

   public String execute(){
    nationalities = new HashMap<String, String>();
    nationalities .put("A","American");
    nationalities .put("B","Canadian");

    return success;
   }
```

.. Please help on how can I properly call these values to be mapped in my jsp?

Thanks a lot.. hope you could give me an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your JSP should look something like this:

```
<s:form action="YourSubmitAction">
    <s:select list="nationalities" name="choosenNationality"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

If you would like to submit chosen value, you have to create action `YourSubmitAction` and don't forget to create `choosenNationality` field of type String with setter - it will be populated with the corresponding key (A/B in your case).

Comment: Hi, Thanks I've actually seen this simple way <s:select list="nationalities" name="choosenNationality"/> in my previews searches. But unfortunately, it doesn't show the options in the hashmap. Before using hashmap in the action class. The implemetation of s:select in jsp is like this <s:select list="#{'A':'American','B':'Canadian'}" name="chooseNationality"/> . I want to retrieve the choices from the action using hashmap instead of hard coding the values in the dropdown.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you want to say but the example I provided is working 100%.

Comment: Thanks PrimosK. I was able to retrieve it thru simple ArrayList and not hashmap... :D

Comment: You should publish and accept your answer so that others can benefit from it.. :) I am glad that you solved it...

Answer (score -1):

```
Below tag iterating over map for displaying it's key and respective values.    
    <s:iterator value="nationalities">
       <s:property value="key" /> <s:property value="value" />
    </s:iterator>
```

Comment: i believe OP want to fill select box with values and not iterator.

Comment: hi  Umesh Awasthi, your right. Before using hashmap in the action class. The implemetation of s:select in jsp is like this <s:select list="#{'A':'American','B':'Canadian'}" name="chooseNationality"/> . I want to retrieve the choices from the action using hashmap instead of hard coding the values in the dropdown.

Comment: Try this example http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/